# VBA String to search file in Windows Explorer

Tags: string, vba, excel

I'm currently recalling a string from a column in an Excel worksheet. I would like to take this string and match it to the file name in Windows Explorer, ultimately creating a hyperlink to the file.

So far, I can loop through the set of file names and return to a message box. I would like to return the string name to search in Windows Explorer. This is the code so far:

```
Sub LoopRange()

    Dim currRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer
    Dim ws As String, quoteID As String

    ws = "Quote LOG"
    currRow = 3
    lastRow = Sheets(ws).Cells(Sheets(ws).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    While currRow <= lastRow
        Sheets(ws).Cells(currRow, 1).Select
        quoteID = ActiveCell.Value
        MsgBox "You've selected row " & currRow & ", " & _
        vbNewLine & "Quote ID: " & quoteID
        currRow = currRow + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*search in windows explorer*"? What do you want to do with the file name?

Comment: Hi Alex K., The string read from the column corresponds to document names of a quote that is stored in a file on a public drive. I would like to use the string to search this file for the corresponding quote.

Comment: Do you actually need to search for the file (eg because it could be in one of several different folders, or because you don't know the full name)?

Comment: The goal is to hyperlink the cell to the file. There are some files missing from incomplete records, so if the file is not in the folder, the macro will (hopefully) move to the next cell.

Comment: So you want to check whether the file exists (with a known file name and location) and insert a hyperlink to the file if it exists?

Comment: Hi Jane, that is exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Dir function to check whether a file exists - just pass in the full path and filename. It will return an empty string if the file does not exist.  I've inserted the Hyperlink in the cell to the left of the quote, but you can obviously adjust that as needed:

```
Sub LoopRange()

    Dim currRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer
    Dim ws As String, quoteID As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim FileName As String
    path = "D:\Documents\"

    ws = "Quote LOG"
    currRow = 3
    lastRow = Sheets(ws).Cells(Sheets(ws).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    While currRow <= lastRow
        Sheets(ws).Cells(currRow, 1).Select
        quoteID = ActiveCell.Value
        FileName = path & quoteID & ".xlsx"
        If Dir(FileName) <> "" And quoteID <> "" Then
            Sheets(ws).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Cells(currRow, 2), Address:=FileName, TextToDisplay:=quoteID
        End If
        currRow = currRow + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Jane. I have some tinkering to do, but this seems to work!